# Greasemonkey scripts in a Windows Phone WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, greasemonkey

I am trying to add additional functionality to a `webBrowser` control using some already written Greasemonkey scripts I have.
Is there a way that I might integrate these into a `webBrowser` control on Windows Phone or will I need to figure out a different way to accomplish this same functionality?

[The specific script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/52341) that I am attempting to get working is called ["BOB"](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/52341).

Comment: Yes, you can port the code.  [What have you tried?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Comment: The [`InvokeScript` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491132.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: Currently I have the webBrowser rendering, however, I've been looking into the possibility of using things like the InvokeScript method. That script would need to be appended into the webpage for the InvokeScript method to work. The script modifies the webpage itself. Thus I was looking for a way to get Grease Monkey to work in a browser, and I haven't found one yet.

Comment: Appending scripts to the webpage is essentially what Greasemonkey does.  The only difference is that GM has a little more protection from the page's code and can optionally access slightly elevated privileges.

Comment: I notice that GM includes a number of special functions such as GM_getValue() and others which are employed by the script I want to use. So can I do something to get grease monkey working or will I need to modify my the script to work without it and then inject it myself?

Comment: Just install and use Firefox (plus Greasemonkey) and be done with it.  Also, that script defines any `GM_` functions, it uses, if they don't exist.  It can probably be injected as-is, and work as the author intended.

Comment: Ah, but I am trying to get this working on Windows Phone, there is no Firefox there which is what brought this issue about.

Comment: Oh.  Google says there was a FF for that, but I see now that it is a [dicey looking build](http://download.pandaapp.com/windows-phone-app/firefox-1.0.0.0-id2279.html).

Comment: I am trying to integrate this into an app, so a FireFox app is not going to be helpful. I need to inject the script into a webpage that I am showing in app. Currently this is being done with a WebBrowser control. I'm going to attempt simply injecting the code into the page. But I have my doubts that that will be successful.